# list index out of range? Python banner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a banner which moves across the screen. I have copied most of this and I'm trying to add new letters but it comes up with an error. Please could you explain to me what this means and how to reach my goal. If there is another way to create a banner(e.g. using tkinter0) I would be grateful if you could show me how.

```
#----------------------------------------------
# Animated Banner Program
#----------------------------------------------

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Challenges:
#
# 1. Change the display width to 5. Note what happens.
# 2. Add more letters to the characters dictionary.
# 3. Make a banner for your name, or a chosen message.
# 4. Allow the user to enter their message.
# 5. Print a border around the edge of the display.
# 6. Allow the user to choose their banner character [*/#/etc.].
#    (HINT: to do this, turn the dictionary into a binary image).
#----------------------------------------------------------------

#allows us to clear the console screen.
import os

import time

#the width of the display
#(the windows console is 79 characters wide).
WIDTH = 79

#the message we wish to print
message = "ABC".upper()
#the printed banner version of the message
#this is a 7-line display, stored as 7 strings
#initially, these are empty.
printedMessage = [ "","","","","","","" ]

#a dictionary mapping letters to their 7-line
#banner display equivalents. each letter in the dictionary
#maps to 7 strings, one for each line of the display.
characters = {" " : [ " ",
                       " ",
                       " ",
                       " ",
                       " ",
                       " ",
                       " " ],

          "A"  : [ "  *  "
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*****"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"],

          "B"  : [ "**** "
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "**** "
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*****"],

          "C"  : [ " *** "
                   "*   *"
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*   *"
                   " *** "],

          "D"  : [ "**** "
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "**** "],

           "E" : [ "*****"
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*****"
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*****"],              

           "F" : [ "*****"
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*****"
                   "*    "
                   "*    "
                   "*    "],

           "G" : [ "*****"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*    "
                   "* ***"
                   "*   *"
                   "*****"],

           "H" : [ "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*****"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"
                   "*   *"],

           "I" :[  "*****"
                   "  *  "
                   "  *  "
                   "  *  "
                   "  *  "
                   "  *  "
                   "*****"],
              }

#build up the printed banner. to do this, the 1st row of the
#display is created for each character in the message, followed by
#the second line, etc..
for row in range(7):
    for char in message:
        printedMessage[row] += (str(characters[char][row]) + "  ")

#the offset is how far to the right we want to print the message.
#initially, we want to print the message just off the display.
offset = WIDTH
while True:
    os.system("cls")
    #print each line of the message, including the offset.
    for row in range(7):
        print(" " * offset + printedMessage[row][max(0,offset*-1):WIDTH - offset])
    #move the message a little to the left.
    offset -=1
    #if the entire message has moved 'through' the display then
    #start again from the right hand side.
    if offset <= ((len(message)+2)*6) * -1:
        offset = WIDTH
    #take out or change this line to speed up / slow down the display
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\banner.py", line 122, in <module>
    printedMessage[row] += (str(characters[char][row]) + "  ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve applies here.  You haven't provided the full error message, so we don't know where the problem occurs.  You haven't cut down the code to a minimal size.  It would also help if you would independently compute and print the index values involved in the failing statement.

Answer (score 1):

Except for your first character (the space), each entry in the dictionary is a list of length one. In python, two strings with only whitespace between them (including linebreaks!) will be interpreted as a single string, so for example

```
[ "  *  "
  "*   *"
  "*   *"
  "*****"
  "*   *"
  "*   *"
  "*   *"]
```

is the same as

```
[ "  *  *   **   *******   **   **   *"]
```

Instead, you probably want to write this as

```
[ "  *  ",
  "*   *",
  "*   *",
  "*****",
  "*   *",
  "*   *",
  "*   *"]
```

so that each row is actually a separate item in the list.

Comment: thank you , it seems to work now and I'm going to try adding more letters